# How can I signal boost a particularly long standing accessibility bug?

Tags: gnome, video, accessibility, zooming

Ever since Ubuntu 19.10, when I turn on the Zoom feature from the accessibility menu, my mouse leaves little square trails running across the screen. 12 others have repro'd this issue, but I suspect it only manifests on large, wide monitors like my 34" curved, so I suspect it's hard to get developers with a similar set-up to help repro.

I just made a Youtube video with my smartphone so you can see this in action. The quality isn't amazing but it's Way Good Enough to witness the bug in action - trying to capture it with screen grabs doesn't work - maybe it's a driver/graphics stack issue I dunno.

Here's the [Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/tjDUHc6nlPs) and here's the bug as reported back in 19.10 timeframe. It's stayed around in 20.04, 20.10.

Here's [the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meta-gnome3/+bug/1872870). I've thought about trying to fix it myself but I'm unsure even how to tell which subsystem is the problem much less where to find the code or how to get into a good debugging state with it.

I'd love any hints or clues anyone has as to how to proceed. I suspect other visually disabled people are being affected too or more likely throwing up their hands and running Windows. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu & flavors are the many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: @guiverc Thank you. I have repro'd this bug in stock Ubuntu 20.10 as well and have eliminated the poisonous mention of the unwelcome OS from my post :) You'll note the original Launchpad bug is an Ubuntu bug, and as I said I found it originally in bog standard Ubuntu 19.10 and have continued to experience it through 20.04 and 20.10.

Comment: Also, while I appreciate the letter of the law regarding the rules of this forum, I have been struggling with this for YEARS at this point and am simply using every avenue at my disposal to seek remediation. If after having removed mention of the non-standard flavor you still feel that my question is inappropriate I'm happy to remove it. Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: What do you want to do here? What is the answer you're looking for?

Comment: Just an FYI:  The package the bug report is failed against was last changed in 2019-Oct-18 for *focal* or 20.04  ie. *the time 19.10 was released & development started*.  It's filed against a package that sees no direct development, and if I had read the bug report when it was filed, I'd likely reply with a *not described well* response and asked for details so it could be changed to point at the correct package.  It doesn't mention what *update* you are referring to (the normal expectation would be the package itself, but it's a package that receives no updates!).

Comment: Yup. Super crappy bug report. I followed instructions I found on filing a bug to the letter but utterly failed at the spirit of the thing :) Thanks very much for the suggestions you made in the bug. I will indeed install 21.04 and retest there. I actually have some hope it may be fixed by the switch to Wayland sessions by default? We'll see :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. New properly categorized bug with 21.04 repro filed as: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1917103

Comment: I'll comment here but this is FYI only, feature freeze on *hirsute* has been passed, which lowers your chance a little for this cycle (depending on the fix required), however with *hirsute* now in the *testing & bug fixing* stage there is still a good chance (I won't go into difference if this seems contradictory which it may; depends on cause & thus fix). I'll wish you luck, and Thank you for helping make Ubuntu better.   (*I won't link reports just yet, I'm hoping it's better if I don't touch it for now, you've left the needed breadcrumbs. Also if you haven't tried MATE, I'd suggest trying*)

Comment: Another off-topic FYI:  but I mentioned "I know two people (developers)*.. " and you've got the attention of one of them (vanvugt) so you've pushed this as far as it can go. We cannot control scheduling/dev-time/etc of Canonical etc...

Comment: I totally understand. Let me re-iterate that I understand this is a volunteer effort so I have been trying to be reasonable and signal boost without being overly pushy or demanding. I apologize pre-emptively if I failed in this.

Comment: You didn't fail at all, and that was not my intention.   My last comment was mostly a :) type post; glad that *we* had success and achieved what I felt was the highest we could achieve.. one of the *two* who has the capacity to fix the issue (though that person has to live within what they can do within their allotted time & capacity as well...   even if it's not fixed in the short-term (as we'd hope), it'll have been noted and will be fixed when it's possible.. ie. it's now in the hands of a Canonical/GNOME person and will be addressed as resources allow...)